# Angular 2 - Preprocessor directives like #if

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to define preprocessor directives on typescript, something like #define #if etc of c#, specially in angular 2?

I´m developing a project that is multiplatform, and I want to use the same code for mobile and web. The problem is when I use a technology that is not supported for one platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a way to define preprocessor directives on typescript, something like #define #if etc of c#, specially in angular 2

No. However the angular team uses webpack and it has the option to define enviroment variables and does dead code elimination on those.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/build-toggles.html

Comment: Thanks!! And I can use it for import or not import some script? Or its just a variable setted by webpack?

Comment: Just a variable set by webpack. You can do more fancy things using webpack e.g. redirecting modules using `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin

Comment: Does this work by any chance with the angular HTML templates?